# how to auto reload camera snapshot

Tags: html, angular

I have an IP Camera which gives me a jpg. 
http://192.168.178.28/tmpfs/auto.jpg?user=USER&pwd=PASSWORD

```
<img [(src)]="linkPicture" alt="profile photo" width="450px" height="450px">
```

OK

now I would reload the image with a timestamp

```
linkPicture = "http://192.168.178.28/tmpfs/auto.jpg?user=USER&pwd=PASSWORD";

setInterval(function(){
    this.timeStamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    this.linkPicture = "http://192.168.178.28/tmpfs/auto.jpg?"+this.timeStamp+"&user=USER&pwd=PASSWORD" ;
    console.log(this.linkPicture);
);}, 2000);
```

but this is not working. Where i have to put the timestamp? at the end of the url? or like i already have?

my img somes me the first "linkPicture" but will not reload... the console shows me every 2 sec. the new linkPicture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your this.linkPicture variable is internal for your interval function and only exists within that scope. That means that you are actually not updating your variable outside.

If you are using babel you can set the function in your interval to an arrow function () => { your code here... } then this would mean the outer scope.

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.timeStamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    this.linkPicture = "http://192.168.178.28/tmpfs/auto.jpg?"+this.timeStamp+"&user=USER&pwd=PASSWORD" ;
    console.log(this.linkPicture);
}, 2000);
```

Or you can bind the context to the outer environment:

```
setInterval(function(){
    this.timeStamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    this.linkPicture = "http://192.168.178.28/tmpfs/auto.jpg?"+this.timeStamp+"&user=USER&pwd=PASSWORD" ;
    console.log(this.linkPicture);
}.bind(this), 2000);
```

And you can also just leave the this before your linkPicture variable and declare the linkPicture variable above as var linkPicture = "your url" and then you can set it inside your interval just as linkPicture = "your new url"

And the sortest solution would be inside your functon just: linkPicture = this.linkPicture